# MongoDB shutting down with code:12

Tags: mongodb

I have saved my data yesterday, but when I tried to open my MongoDB via command Prompt  and fire the command `mongod` its throwing out the following messages

```
>C:\mongodb\bin>mongod
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.350+0530 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, >to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.842+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : >pid=13544 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-4H7RM2O
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.842+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows >7/Windows Server 2008 R2
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.843+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.0
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.843+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: >3b07af3d4f471ae89e8186d33bbb1d5259597d51
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.843+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.843+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.843+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.843+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus->ssl
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.843+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.843+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.844+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.844+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in >initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., >terminating
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.844+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
>2018-07-20T16:21:25.844+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with >code:100
>
**Here is the command Prompt output when I fire mongo command**

    <C:\mongodb\bin>mongo
    <MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
    <connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
    <2018-07-20T16:28:01.594+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server <127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to <127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target <machine actively refused it. :
    <connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
    <@(connect):1:6
    <exception: connect failed
```

**This is my log file which is showing error  =shutting down with code:12 **

```
>2018-07-20T15:43:37.425+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access >control is not enabled for the database.
>2018-07-20T15:43:37.425+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and >write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
>2018-07-20T15:43:37.425+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>2018-07-20T15:43:37.425+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server >is bound to localhost.
>2018-07-20T15:43:37.425+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote >systems will be unable to connect to this server. 
>2018-07-20T15:43:37.425+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the >server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 
>2018-07-20T15:43:37.425+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it >should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
>2018-07-20T15:43:37.426+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all >interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
>2018-07-20T15:43:37.426+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with >--bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
>2018-07-20T15:43:37.426+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>2018-07-20T15:43:40.388+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time >diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/mongodb/data/db/diagnostic.data'
>2018-07-20T15:43:40.499+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections >on port 27017
>2018-07-20T15:45:42.106+0530 I CONTROL  [thread1] Ctrl-C signal
>2018-07-20T15:45:42.106+0530 I CONTROL  [consoleTerminate] got CTRL_C_EVENT, >will terminate after current cmd ends
>2018-07-20T15:45:42.106+0530 I NETWORK  [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to >close listening sockets...
>2018-07-20T15:45:42.325+0530 I CONTROL  [consoleTerminate] Shutting down free >monitoring
>2018-07-20T15:45:42.326+0530 I FTDC     [consoleTerminate] Shutting down full->time diagnostic data capture
>2018-07-20T15:45:42.334+0530 I STORAGE  [consoleTerminate] WiredTigerKVEngine >shutting down
>2018-07-20T15:45:45.543+0530 I STORAGE  [consoleTerminate] shutdown: removing fs >lock...
>2018-07-20T15:45:45.543+0530 I CONTROL  [consoleTerminate] now exiting
>2018-07-20T15:45:45.543+0530 I CONTROL  [consoleTerminate] shutting down with >code:12
```

I have ensured that my data path is correct but unable to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
Mac: Documents/mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath Documents/data/db/
Window: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data
```

You just need to set `db` path.

You can set storage db path to the config file: [Check this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath)

And [check this](https://docs.mongodb.com/tutorials/install-mongodb-on-windows/#install-mongodb-community-edition) for window installation.

Comment: So, when you have accepted my answer, It was working perfectly. Now it is not. `exception in &gt;initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found.` this is clearly said that your mongo could not find path while starting. You need to set path every time or please double check that your mongo find path perfectly while starting. Double check your configuration.

Comment: And one more thing is, you have setted different path and your mongo taking different path while start. Double check your configuration or just try my command every time when you start mongo.

Comment: yes, I had reinstall MongoDB to your mentioned path, now its working fine,  thanks for your kind effort

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux just give increased permission to the storage file and restart mongodb it will work. Default storage file will be var/lib/mongodb. To give increased permissions use : chmod 777 mongod.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have mounted the mongo `/data/db` into a local folder with this command:

```bash
    volumes:

      - "./configs/mongodb_data:/data/db"
```

Then you should run this command to recovery the data:

```bash
chmod 777 /root/it_has_alternatives/configs/mongodb_data

docker container run --rm -v /root/it_has_alternatives/configs/mongodb_data:/data/db mongo:6.0.4-jammy mongod --repair
```

---

If your docker has some serious problem, you could run the following command to repair it:

- Make sure all docker containers are down: `docker compose down`
- Remove problematic overlay2: `sudo rm -R /var/lib/docker/overlay2`
- Remove images: `sudo rm -R /var/lib/docker/image`
- Clear any other cached data: `sudo docker system prune -f`
- Restart docker service: `sudo systemctl restart docker`